# PyMySql pass query as a parameter to sql statement

Tags: python, pymysql

Fairly knowledgeable with passing parameters to a SELECT statement using pymysql and python.  Just throwing this out there but is it possible to pass a query as a parameter to a sql statement?  Something like:

```
sqlCmd = """SELECT * from mytable where coadataid=%s"""
cur.execute(sqlCmd,("""ANY(SELECT recordid FROM coadata WHERE flowtype='1')""",))
```

Obviously, the above will not work but I am looking for a way to get something like this TO work.  An y ideas?

Comment: Seems to me you have two queries, and you are trying to pass the result of the first query as a parameter for the second. Is this assumption right?

Comment: Actually, not really: The final query passed to the server should look like this:
`SELECT * from mytable WHERE coadataid=ANY(SELECT recordid FROM coadata WHERE flowtype='1')`

Answer (score 0):

Parameters are always substituted as literal values, they're not expressions that will be evaluated by MySQL. That's how parameters prevent SQL injection.

You can use normal string formatting to substitute the subquery into the main query, and `cursor.execute()` parameters to fill in the values in the subquery.

```
cur.execute(sqlCmd % ("""ANY(SELECT recordid FROM coadata WHERE flowtype=%s)""",), ('1',))
```

Comment: ANY is strictly internal.  Trying to build a generic class for the table that will allow me to pass filters or parameters.

Comment: You're trying to design your own ORM instead of using something that already exists like SQLAlchemy?

Comment: No, just a couple of custom classes.

Comment: So you want to build `WHERE flowtype = '1'` dynamically from filtering parameters? That's a completely different question.

Comment: Just looking for a way to pass the WHERE clause in as a filter.  Refer to my original question.  The two tables are relationally connected.

Comment: I explained why you can't do that. You have to build the WHERE clause dynamically, e.g. `WHERE flowtype = %s`. Then you can use a parameter to fill in the `%s`.

Comment: You can't use parameters for queries, clauses, table or column names, etc. They can only be used where a value is needed, and the parameter will be a literal value.

Comment: That's not the query, Bro!  I'm qualifying a result set based on the contents of another table.  flowtype is not a part of the table I am querying.  You said it can't be done - I'm fine with that answer.  Thank you.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. I meant that that would be part of the subquery that you build dynamically.

Comment: I'm fairly proficient with that.  I just wanted to know if what I wanted could be done. If so, how.  If not - no worries.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you mix the two forms of substitution.